# XPath read values from sql table column

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

I have below xml present as a column(Name UserBody) value of the table called tblUsers.

I have to read NewUserType  name i.e. "SampleUserName" using Xpath in SQL.

```
<UserTypeAdded xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Domain.Contract.EventModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <UserTypeTypeDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Common.Contract">
            <a:Id>550d9a76-3d7d-49f6-9243-f0473d32b123</a:Id>
            <a:Name>Special User Types</a:Name>
        </UserTypeTypeDetails>
        <NewUserType xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Domain.Contract.Base">
            <Id xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Common.Contract">dfa090ff-9756-42fd-be9b-02ac8c6b123</Id>
            <Name xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Common.Contract">SampleUserName</Name>
        </NewUserType>
    </UserTypeAdded>
```

I tried using below statement

```
   SELECT 
    [UserBody].value('(/UserTypeAdded/NewUserType/Name[1])', 'nvarchar(max)') as UserName 
    FROM tblUsers
```

but No luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined your node incorrectly, you have:

```
'(/UserTypeAdded/NewUserType/Name[1])'
```

You either need to specify the position of each element:

```
'(/UserTypeAdded[1]/NewUserType[1]/Name[1])'
```

Or wrap the entire path in parenethesis and specify the position for that:

```
'(/UserTypeAdded/NewUserType/Name)[1]'
```

You also need to define your XML Namespaces:

```
-- SAMPLE DATA
DECLARE @tblUsers TABLE (UserBody XML);
INSERT @Tblusers 
VALUES('<UserTypeAdded xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Domain.Contract.EventModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <UserTypeTypeDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Common.Contract">
            <a:Id>550d9a76-3d7d-49f6-9243-f0473d32b123</a:Id>
            <a:Name>Special User Types</a:Name>
        </UserTypeTypeDetails>
        <NewUserType xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Domain.Contract.Base">
            <Id xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Common.Contract">dfa090ff-9756-42fd-be9b-02ac8c6b123</Id>
            <Name xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Common.Contract">SampleUserName</Name>
        </NewUserType>
    </UserTypeAdded>');

-- QUERY
WITH XMLNAMESPACES
(   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Domain.Contract.Base' AS a,
    'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Common.Contract' AS x,
    DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Domain.Contract.EventModel'
)
SELECT *,
        UserBody.value('(/UserTypeAdded/NewUserType/x:Name)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as UserName
FROM @TblUsers;
```

You can also use a wild card for namespaces:

```
SELECT *,
        UserBody.value('(/*:UserTypeAdded/*:NewUserType/*:Name)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as UserName
FROM @TblUsers;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is full of different namespaces which you need to consider in your XQuery. You can use [`WITH XMLNAMESPACES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx) to map prefix to namespace URI, and use the prefix to reference element in namespace, for example :

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
(
    'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Domain.Contract.EventModel' as utaNs,
    'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Common.Contract' as nameNs
)
SELECT 
    [UserBody].value('(/utaNs:UserTypeAdded/utaNs:NewUserType/nameNs:Name)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as UserName 
FROM tblUsers
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @x.value('(/*:UserTypeAdded/*:NewUserType/*:Name)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
declare @XML xml = '
<UserTypeAdded xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Domain.Contract.EventModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <UserTypeTypeDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Common.Contract">
            <a:Id>550d9a76-3d7d-49f6-9243-f0473d32b123</a:Id>
            <a:Name>Special User Types</a:Name>
        </UserTypeTypeDetails>
        <NewUserType xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Domain.Contract.Base">
            <Id xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Common.Contract">dfa090ff-9756-42fd-be9b-02ac8c6b123</Id>
            <Name xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ABC.Common.Contract">SampleUserName</Name>
        </NewUserType>
    </UserTypeAdded>'


select T.N.value('(/*:UserTypeAdded/*:NewUserType/*:Name)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as UserName 
from @XML.nodes('/*:UserTypeAdded') as T(N)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query .

```
     SELECT  [UserBody].value('(/UserTypeAdded/NewUserType/Name)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as UserName 
    FROM tblUsers
```